# query mongodb Or fields?

Tags: mongodb

How do I query mongodb with or on two different fields.

For example I want `{ fieldA : true }`, or `{fieldB : true}`. Either of those would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_or) operator:

```js
db.test.find({ $or: [{fieldA : true}, {fieldB : true}]})
```